# Keep only specific strings in a column, otherwise convert to NA

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I would like to keep selected strings in a column (A1, B2), and the rest NOT DELETE them, but replace them for NA.
I have seen other posts regarding deleting the rows, or partially replacing text, but I would like to replace them with NA, and I cannot find the right command/function.

```
myDf <- structure(list(GeogPreferences = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A1", 
"B1", "A2", "B2"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Letters", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Not this but something like

```
keep[, c=("A1", "B2")]
other ways replace with gsub( "non-keep", "NA", as.character(myDf$Letter) n)
```

Current myDf:

```
   Letters
1  A1
2  B1
3  A2
4  B2
```

Desired:

```
   Letters
1  A1
2  NA
3  NA
4  B2
```

Comment: `myDf %>% 
   mutate(Letters = ifelse(Letters %in% c("A1","B2"),as.character(Letters),NA))` but there might be a way to do it without converting to character first. I have also written something that does the same with `mde:recode_as_na_str` where you can supply a regex.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks @NelsonGon ! I like the mutate function but I am still familiarising with its potentiall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for `within`.

```
keep <- c("A2", "B1")
within(myDf, Letters[!Letters %in% keep] <- NA)
#   Letters
# 1    <NA>
# 2      B1
# 3      A2
# 4    <NA>
```